# Use .htaccess to rewrite requests for a PNG as a PHP GET variable

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm REALLY bad with .htaccess files, and reading through the existing questions on SO only confuse me more (mainly because they're all situation-specific and don't *exactly* apply to my situation at hand). I'm making a script that generates dynamic images through PHP. The script takes 1 variable, which makes the URL look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/script/image.php?name=esqew
```

However, I'd like to utilize an .htaccess file to rewrite the file to something more elegant and something my users can use on forums, like so:

```
http://www.example.com/script/esqew.png
```

The question, in a nutshell, is how do I rewrite the first request above to something more elegant like the second example using .htaccess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^script/(\w+)\.png$ script/image.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This assumes name is at least 1 alphanumeric or underscore character. It will also only work for png extensions.

Comment: Should I put this in my .htaccess within the directory, or at the root of my site?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(script)/([^.]*)\.png$ $1/image.php?name=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the other guy beat you by just a few seconds. :)

Comment: Agreed and quite similar answers too, except that I am using `[^.]` instead of `\w` :)

Comment: IMO, `[^.]` is too open in such a case assuming the OP is matching a filename.

Comment: Nope, because a valid filename can very well be `esqew-1` and in that case `\w+` will **NOT** match.